# Where do I put my tongue?

Tags: произношение

I'm an absolute beginner with Russian, and am really struggling to simply pronounce some of the sounds! I remember when I learned Chinese I found a website guide on where to put my tongue (and also how far back in the mouth/throat to make the sound), which turned out to be incredibly useful. Does anyone know of something similar for Russian?

Comment: You can try this: http://www.portal-slovo.ru/pre_school_education/42743.php

Comment: @RomanPetrenko Thanks! Judging by what Google Translate gives me, that would be perfect if it was in English.

Answer (score 4):

Here is detailed description for pronunciation of vowels and consonants, and also some other useful articles: http://masterrussian.com/index-6.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I recently re-started trying to learn Russian, and this video course (requires signup, but would be accessible during the free 7-day trial) is exactly what I was after:
https://www.russianpod101.com/lesson-library/ultimate-russian-pronunciation-guide/

It has diagrams showing where the tongue should go, as well as detailed explanations of where to put each part of your tongue, how to adapt the nearest sound in English, as well as the native speaker saying each letter by itself and in words.